# I am receiving an 'access is denied' message when using mysqldump.exe to backup my database. Any idea why?

Tags: mysql, access-denied

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -u root -p bookstore > \bookstore.sql
```

I used the command above before receiving the following message:

> Access is denied.

I believe it may be because mysql may not have permission to write files directly to the C drive, though i am the admin, so i cannot understand why.

thanks for you input!

Comment: Do you enter the correct password? Is this the whole error message?

Comment: Did you try `c:\bookstore.sql` instead of `\bookstore.sql`?

Comment: The command i used was correct, it turns out it was a UAC issue. i just changed my user access control level from the user account settings in control panel. Thanks for your input though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Adjust User Account Control settings to allow programs to write directly to the C drive.

Control Panel > User Accounts and Family Safety > User Accounts > Change User Account Control settings